# Good way to store data hierarchically?

Tags: database, information-management, todo

I'm looking for a way to create a tree (data structure) of places to visit in life.
I would like to have hierarchy like this

```
Continent
I- Country
    I- Region
        I- Sight to visit
            I- Subsight
```

e.g.

```
I- America
I---I- USA
I   I---I- California
I       I---I- Death Valley
I       I---I- San Francisco
I           I---I- Golden Gate Bridge
I- Europe
I---I- Italy
    I---I- Whole Country
        I--- Rome
```

For each node, I would like to have some predefined types data saved (mainly: visited by Person A, Person B (so binary), type of sight, maybe some notes (text)). This data should be usable for filtering (e.g. not visited by Person A AND not visited by Person B).

To some degree using trees of a file system would actually work quite well but of course, it's not really practical.

Do you know a good way to store this kind of data (Windows Tool or web application (PHP/SQL))?

I tried Excel but it's really practical to use.

Comment: XML is good for storing this kind of structure.

Comment: XML, XML, XML - Unlimited possibilities with XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an excellent PIM/outliner called [Treeline](http://www.treeline.bellz.org/index.html) that is freely available (GNU GPL) and runs under Windows and Linux.

[image: treeline screenshot]

There is a small, but reasonably gentle learning curve. It comes with a number of small sample files/databases to illustrate its chief features. The example of the book catalogue (screenshot above) shows how the categories could "map" to OP's example:

> `SF Books > Read > Author > Title > Info`

in the screeshot could be seen as analogous to:

> `Continent > Country > Region > Site > Subsite`

in OP's spec. I think it will do exactly what is required.

---

P.s. In light of a couple comments on the Question, it's worth noting this item among Treeline's feature set:

> Generic XML files can be imported and exported, allowing TreeLine to function as a crude XML editor.