# offline Snippet Manager

Tags: windows, software-development, portable

I'm looking for a program to save snippet for future use, and with following requirements:

- Offline
  Some office are not allow to access internet or with limitation
- Portable
  I don't have admin right, which means I can't install anything.
  Moreover, for future, I can email whole stuff for backup.
- Have syntax highlight
- Can be categorize
  Having tag is a bonus
- Free to use in office
  I use it for personal, but it may count as commercial use in office, like *PhraseExpress*.

Comment: Closely related question: [*Offline Code Snippet Manager*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/41674/offline-code-snippet-manager/72340)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Breevy](http://www.16software.com/breevy/)

- Offline
- Portable
- Has categories

It doesn't have syntax highlight though.

[image: Breevy GUI]